# Why isn't pattern matching on an assigned value recognized

Tags: f#

**Why isn't pattern matching on an assigned value recognized**

I receive a warning when I attempt to pattern match on the value called target:

```
[<Test>]
let ``set center cell to alive``() =
    // Setup
    let target = (2,2)

    let grid = createGrid 9 |> Map.map (fun k v -> 
                                            match k with
                                            | target -> { v with Status=Alive }
                                            | _      -> v)
    // Test
    let center = grid |> getStatus (2,2)

    // Verify
    center |> should equal Alive
```

The warning points to:

```
| target -> { v with Status=Alive }
| _      -> v)
```

Specifically on:

```
| _      -> v)
```

The warning is:

> This rule will never be reached.

Which forces me to not use target and instead hard-code the value in order to resolve the warning:

```
[<Test>]
let ``set center cell to alive``() =
    // Setup
    let grid = createGrid 9 |> Map.map (fun k v -> 
                                            match k with
                                            | (2,2) -> { v with Status=Alive }
                                            | _     -> v)
    // Test
    let center = grid |> getStatus (2,2)

    // Verify
    center |> should equal Alive
```

**Can someone explain why I can't do this?**

**Full code:**

```
type Status = Alive | Dead
type Cell = { X:int; Y:int; Status:Status }

let isNeighbor cell1 cell2 =

    let isAbsNeighbor v1 v2 =
        match abs (v1 - v2) with
        | 0 | 1 -> true
        | _     -> false

    let isValueNeighbor v1 v2 =
        match v1 >= 0
          &&  v2 >= 0 with
        | true  -> isAbsNeighbor v1 v2
        | _     -> isAbsNeighbor v2 v1

    match cell1.X <> cell2.X
      ||  cell1.Y <> cell2.Y with
    | true ->   isValueNeighbor cell1.X cell2.X
             && isValueNeighbor cell1.Y cell2.Y
    | _    -> false

let createGrid rowCount = 

    [for x in 1..rowCount do
        for y in 1..rowCount do
            yield { X=x; Y=y; Status=Dead } ]
    |> List.map (fun c -> (c.X, c.Y), { X=c.X; Y=c.Y; Status=Dead })
    |> Map.ofList

let getStatus coordinate (grid:Map<(int * int), Cell>) =

    match grid.TryFind coordinate with
    | Some cell -> cell.Status
    | None      -> Dead
```

Answer (score 8):

In a `match` expression, the rule

```
match k with
| target -> { v with Status=Alive }
```

unconditionally matches and binds `k` to a name `target` which shadows the existing definition. This means the following clause will never be reached. You can use a conditional match:

```
match k with
| t when t = target -> { v with Status = Alive }
| _ -> v
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [Pattern Matching](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547125.aspx) your `target` is a *variable pattern*, so it shadows the original target value.

Pattern matching is useful for *destructuring* the matched object, for a simple test plain `if-else` is preferrable (in my opinion).

A use-case for pattern matching would be if you want to test several cases. Instead of a [when guard](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233242.aspx) you could then also use [active patterns](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233248.aspx):

```
let (|Eq|_|) expected actual =
    if expected = actual then Some()
    else None

let target = (2,2)

let attempt = (3,2)

match attempt with
| Eq target -> Some "Bulls eye"
| (2, _) -> Some "Almost"
| t when fst t > 20 -> Some "Quite the contrary"
| _ -> None
```